# LaCie NAS failed - Recover Raid 5 From bad device

Tags: raid, data-recovery, nas, raid-5

here is my problem: I have a 5disk (Seagate 2To) RAID5 working with a NAS LaCie 5big. Each disk is still working but the NAS device has failed and it refuses to boot with HDD inside (LaCie helpdesk don't want to help me). And I badly need to recover my data from my RAID. I don't how to do. I've connected my disk to my PC, each of them is recognized but then ... I'm lost. I know the order of the drives in the RAID, but that's all, I 'don't know the format, of the way the RAID was managed by LaCie and can't find information about that in Help/manual provided by LaCie.

*LaCie device failure

*5 out of 5 drives working

*format unkown

LSBLK

> sdb       8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk

- ├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part
- ├─sdb2    8:18   0   1,8T  0 part
- ├─sdb3    8:19   0   934K  0 part
- ├─sdb4    8:20   0     1M  0 part
- ├─sdb5    8:21   0   250M  0 part [SWAP]
- ├─sdb6    8:22   0   7,9M  0 part
- ├─sdb7    8:23   0  15,7M  0 part
- ├─sdb8    8:24   0 823,7M  0 part
- ├─sdb9    8:25   0   855M  0 part
- └─sdb10   8:26   0   7,9M  0 part

FDISK

> Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0x00000000

- Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
- /dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

PARTED

> Model: ATA ST2000DL003-9VT1 (scsi)
> Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
> Partition Table: gpt

- Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
- 5      0,00GB  0,26GB  0,26GB  linux-swap(v1)  primary
- 6      0,27GB  0,28GB  0,01GB                  primary
- 7      0,28GB  0,30GB  0,02GB  ext3            primary
- 8      0,30GB  1,16GB  0,86GB  ext3            primary
- 9      1,16GB  2,06GB  0,90GB  ext3            primary
- 10      2,06GB  2,07GB  0,01GB                  primary
- 1      2,07GB  2,07GB  0,00GB                  primary
- 3      2,07GB  2,07GB  0,00GB                  primary
- 4      2,07GB  2,07GB  0,00GB                  primary
- 2      2,07GB  2000GB  1998GB                  primary

MDADM Produces (2 out of 5 drives plugged)

> mdadm --scan --examine >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

- ## definitions of existing MD arrays
- ARRAY /dev/md/4 metadata=1.0 UUID=02ddd768:323b4b87:e56926a1:e03b01f2
  name=LaCie-5big:4
- ARRAY /dev/md3 UUID=88db5732:95381109:3d186b3c:53958f34
- ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=e77c7ed4:72479a3e:3d186b3c:53958f34
- ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=9d2ffd1b:c2b6746f:3d186b3c:53958f34
- ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=6c40830c:b9cf3361:3d186b3c:53958f34
  Guess it's Fake Raid?

[image]

Comment: I am assuming that the lacie big 5 uses software RAID via mdadm. Can you check that by connecting one disk from the NAX attached to your desktop and then boot a Linux liveCD? (do not try to modify anything. Just list the partition table of the disk and add it to your post).  (If I am right then you are 5 sata cables and oine mdadm -scan / assemble away from your data).

Comment: I'll give you that, and thank you for redirecting me to SU

Comment: Okay I added partition table, also according to information I could read about LaCie RAID partition are XFS formated.

Comment: I tried to make sense of it but I can't form a clear picture. Why did the LB5 create this many partitions? I can understand separate /boot, / and swap. And the main data partition. But more seems overkill. Instead we have 10 partitions, 3 in ext3, one swap, the rest unknown.  And no less than 5 md entries.  * puzzled *

Comment: I think I have the same problem with Lacie 5big, and I don't know  how to recover. Did you achieve it? How do you connect 5 drives to a pc?

Answer (score 1):

Okay according to those threads :

1. [Tom's Hardware forum - recover mirrored raid device failure](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-252747_14_0.html)
2. [Mike Taulty's blog - recover Lacie 2Big](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/06/17/lacie-2big-nas-recovering-data-with-good-drives-bad-device.aspx)

   - I need xfsprogs, cause Lacie main partition are XFS formated.
   - Need to mount those partitions of each 5 drives from the RAID5
   - Using mdadm assemble the raid back

I guess few step are missing I'll keep on looking for a workaround and edit this answer

Comment: Each of 5 drives would be optimal. But it you formatted as RAID-5 then you should be able to read all the data with just 4 drives.